# Jenkins: Deleting Old Builds

Tags: java, jenkins, build, settings, config

How to delete old Jenkins builds manually? I used Discard Old Builds plugin and set to keep last 10 builds. It is not working perfectly and keeping 13 builds.
Is there any proper way even to do it manually so that build numbers [#1 #2 ...etc] will also be reorganised?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin Have a look in this

Comment: Wow using same plugin but it working right. Maybe you have builds which marked to keep forever? Also old builds deleted after new one executed.

Comment: :-)..No. I have no builds marked as that. And after installing that plugin I started new builds so that I can see the result. If it is working fine for your case than..Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind scripting the deletion algorithm yourself, you can easily create something in [Groovy Postbuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

For example, if you wanted to keep the last 10 builds and delete the rest, copy and paste this one liner in the groovy postbuild step:

```
manager.build.parent.builds.drop(10).each { it.delete() }
```

What's good about this approach is that you have *full* control over how things are deleted.  For example, you could easily do something fancy like delete builds based on a logarithmic approach with older builds dropping off faster than newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

Other than setting up "max number of builds to keep". There's a "delete this build option" associated with every build when you click on them, but you need to have admin privilege to delete it. Another way to do it is, from the server. Go to the directory where builds are archived and remove them. Path looks like below.

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<jobname>/builds
```